# Screen Time: App Limits removed but still applying

Tags: ios, parental-controls, screen-time

I previously set up App Limits for myself but decided to remove them yesterday. However, my use of the apps was still limited today. Afterwards, I tried disabling app usage tracking completely to see if I would regain access to the apps, but it didn’t work, despite the usage data having seemingly been deleted (judging by the bar graphs) and me having to set up a new Screen Time password.

My device is an iPhone 8 running iOS 16.1.2.